# How to state uniqueness mathematically using predicates?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

I have always seen in classes at university theorems, proofs, corrollaries etc... stating that, for example, that there $\exists b\in \mathbb{N}$ such that b is unique.  However, after taking this course which taught us a lot about writing this in mathematical terms, I was wondering how would you formally write that a term is unique.

Example: $∀a,n∈N,\exists b\in \mathbb N, b < n \land ab \equiv_n 1.$
How would you add to this statement that not only $b$ exists but $b$ is unique?  Other than just putting ∃!?

Comment: The statement in your example is lacking the definitions of $a$ and $n$, as well as a quantifier on each one of them. For example, did you mean to start it with "$\forall a,n\in\mathbb N$"?

Comment: I think you'll find the notation "$\exists!$" is nearly universally used

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that part.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: OK, so you can add to your statement "$\wedge(\forall c\in\mathbb N,c\geq n \vee ac\not\equiv_n1)$".

Comment: BTW, your statement is not true for $n=$ the smallest element in $\mathbb N$ (whether your consider $0\in\mathbb N$ or not), since there is obviously no $b\in\mathbb N,b<n$.

Comment: The "definition" of "$\exists! x,\ P(x)$" is $$\exists x,\ (P(x)\wedge \forall y,\ (\neg P(y)\vee x=y))$$ since it's a bit lengthy, it's never written explicitly.